# pandas grouping data frame - python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataset,

```
PRODUCT_ID   SALE_DATE   SALE_PRICE PROVIDER
1            01/02/16    25         1
1            02/10/16    60         1
1            01/11/16    63         2
1            09/10/16    65         3
2            11/11/15    54         1
2            13/01/16    34         2
3            19/05/14    45         1
3            15/10/15    38         1
3            16/06/14    53         2
3            18/10/15    58         2
```

This is a combined dataset, data provided by different providers, there is no common identifier for each sale. The issue here is each data provider will have slightly different date and price for each sale. So I am trying to group them together as single sale with a group id. So the business logic here is data provider 1 is the first to get sale data, so for a product id, if the sale date from provider 2 or 3 is within 1 month time and the price is within 10$ difference (more or less), we consider them as same sale, else it will be considered as different sale. So, the output should look like,

```
PRODUCT_ID   SALE_DATE   SALE_PRICE PROVIDER  SALE_GROUP_ID
1            01/02/16    25         1          1
1            02/10/16    60         1          2
1            01/11/16    63         2          2
1            09/10/16    65         3          2
2            11/11/15    54         1          3 
2            13/01/16    34         2          4
3            19/05/14    45         1          5
3            15/10/15    38         1          6
3            16/06/14    53         2          5
3            18/10/15    58         2          7
```

How do I achieve this in pandas, can someone help please? Thanks.

Comment: `18/10/15` and `11/11/15` are within one month and have $10 in price difference. Are they same sale?

Comment: Nope. Because, they have different product_id. PRODUCT_ID should be the same to be considered as same sale..

Comment: `19/05/14` and `16/06/14` have same PRODUCT_ID, are within one month, have $10 in price difference, and are same sale. Do their sale IDs need to be in sequence?

Comment: Yes, that is why they are considered as same sale. Product_ID is same, within one month and have 10$ difference. So considered as same sale and sale_group_id is same. Nope, they don't need to be in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can using `groupby` after `sort_values`

```
df.SALE_DATE=pd.to_datetime(df.SALE_DATE,format='%d/%m/%y')
df=df.sort_values(['PRODUCT_ID','SALE_DATE','SALE_PRICE'])
df1=df.copy()
df1=df.copy().sort_index()


df1['SALE_GROUP_ID']=df.groupby([df['PRODUCT_ID'],(df['SALE_DATE'].diff().abs()/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')).lt(1).ne(1).cumsum(),df['SALE_PRICE'].diff().lt(10).ne(1).cumsum()]).ngroup().add(1).sort_index().values
df1
Out[294]: 
   PRODUCT_ID  SALE_DATE  SALE_PRICE  PROVIDER  SALE_GROUP_ID
0           1 2016-02-01          25         1              1
1           1 2016-10-02          60         1              2
2           1 2016-11-01          63         2              2
3           1 2016-10-09          65         3              2
4           2 2015-11-11          54         1              3
5           2 2016-01-13          34         2              4
6           3 2014-05-19          45         1              5
7           3 2015-10-15          38         1              6
8           3 2014-06-16          53         2              5
9           3 2015-10-18          58         2              7
```

More info: you require 3 condition when get the group ,

```
 1. PRODUCT_ID
 2. Date different within in 1 month
 3. SALE_PRICE different less than 10
```

`(df['SALE_DATE'].diff().abs()/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')).lt(1).ne(1).cumsum()`, is to getthing the group of date within one month

```
(df['SALE_DATE'].diff().abs()/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')).lt(1).ne(1).cumsum()
Out[274]: 
0    1
1    2
3    2
2    2
4    3
5    4
6    5
8    5
7    6
9    6
Name: SALE_DATE, dtype: int32
```

`df['SALE_PRICE'].diff().lt(10).ne(1).cumsum()` is to get the value within 10

```
df['SALE_PRICE'].diff().lt(10).ne(1).cumsum()
Out[275]: 
0    1
1    2
3    2
2    2
4    2
5    2
6    3
8    3
7    3
9    4
Name: SALE_PRICE, dtype: int32
```

After the `groupby` we just combine (getting the intersection of each group condition), then we using `ngroup` to get the group Id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161557/discussion-between-ds-user-and-wen).

Comment: @ds_user sorry I can not using the chat ,, you can change to `df['SALE_DATE'].diff()/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')`  this part lt(50) is to handle the bin size

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand this.  So to mention the day difference, I have to modify 'lt' alone or this also np.timedelta64(1, 'D') to np.timedelta64(50, 'D') . Is this correct ? `df['sale_date'].diff().abs()/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).lt(50).ne(1).cumsum(),df['net_sale_price'].pct_change().lt(0.1).ne(1).cumsum()` ?

Comment: @ds_user you just need to np.timedelta64(1, 'D'), this is to convert the days object to int